# Mould in oven due to leftover food

Tags: oven, cleaning, mold

I have some mould in my oven due to accidentally leaving food in there. The food has been removed but there is mould in the oven. Can I turn the fan oven function on to kill the mould spores before I clean it or should I just turn the grill on. Any advice would be welcome.
Thanks

Comment: probable duplicate: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/82860/moldy-food-left-in-oven-safe-to-cook?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moldy food left in oven, safe to cook?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/82860/moldy-food-left-in-oven-safe-to-cook)

Answer (score 3):

Mold spores are easily destroyed by heat, so I would just turn on the oven and set it to bake at 400°F/200°C (or hotter if you'd like). After this, clean the oven. If you clean the oven first, you could spread some of the spores around your kitchen or breathe them in. If you really want to go nuts, you can use the self-cleaning function of your oven, but this is unnecessary. Most mold spores will be destroyed by the time your oven reaches 200°F, but there are some thermophilic molds that require a higher temperature to destroy them. Leave the oven on for 30 minutes and you should be fine and can then finish cleaning the oven.